# "I made it my prime objective settling the matter." - unacceptable extraposition

Tags: extraposition

Just saw this sentence marked as unacceptable in Quirke's Comprehensive Grammar (18.35 Extraposition of a clausal object):

> *I made it my prime objective settling the matter

The full bit:

[image]

I don't understand why this construction was deemed unacceptable. What's so different between it and 'I made it my objective to settle the matter' and the rest ? Both 'to settle...' and 'settling...' are clausal objects, no? And it says right there that -ing clauses can undergo extraposition. No further explanation is given in the chapter, so I'm a bit confused here. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: To determine acceptability / unacceptability of a sentence say, a panel of articulate Anglophones is set up and the sample sentence run past them. They vote on whether they find it acceptable or not (they may possibly be asked to use a five-point Likert-like scale rather than merely say yea or nay). The results are averaged, and an arbitrary score set as the borderline for acceptability. Quirk/Svartvik suggested that using levels of acceptability rather than a pass / fail decision provided a better model. // Similar-looking or even similar sentences may receive different acceptability ratings.

Comment: I find them all clumsy. 'I made my prime objective to be the settling of the matter' is the only way I feel comfortable expressing this idea.

Comment: In all fairness, these fine points may be useful for those who are interested in writing idiomatic English, but they are not hard and fast rules and they are liable to evolve over time. The reason is mechanical: if a grammar rule sounds too complicated for people to understand or teach, it cannot be enforced. If it cannot be enforced, there is risk it *will* be violated and what sounded "unacceptable" might become "acceptable".

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth So that's how it works. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: There does appear to be inconsistency here in ACGEL. Perhaps an 'in some cases' needs to be inserted.

Comment: @fralau: "If a grammar rule sounds too complicated for people to understand and teach, it cannot be enforced." Where do you get that? Language evolves, and constructions that previously sounded "unacceptable" end up sounding "acceptable". Whether or not they're too complicated to teach has nothing to do with this process. (To be continued.)

Comment: ...  @fralau: For a counterexample, consider the rule "never split an infinitive". Incredibly easy to state, but it was unacceptable to split infinitives 200 years ago, and now it's done all the time. And please give me a simple explanation of when to use "except" and when "except for". I've never seen a simple, correct explanation of this grammar, but most native speakers understand it intuitively.

Comment: @Peter Shor I am not sure where the contradiction is between those two statements: "teaching a complicated rule is impractical" and "language evolves"? My comment is pragmatic, i.e. if one tries to teach a grammar rule that students cannot understand, they won't be able to apply it correctly. It has no significance beyond that observation.

Answer (score 1):

It is my prime objective to settle the matter.

My prime objective is to settle the matter.

The first example introduces "it" which serves to move the subject away from the subject position.

The second example eliminates the need for it, which makes the sentence more concise. For general usage, I don't think it matters. For academic or certain other genres, where the rule is to be more precise, it is helpful to eliminate the "it." Ultimately what you place in subject position is a matter of emphasis, for instance:

Settling the matter is my prime objective. 
Moves the emphasis from 'my prime directive' to:'settling the matter.' 
Though the distinction in some cases is negligible.

A good source for the 'extraposition' is: 
https://www.thoughtco.com/extraposition-grammar-term-1690626

My favorite grammar book is *The Grammar Book* 3rd Edition Dianne Larsen-Freeman and Marianne Celce-Murcia. (p.25) Theme/Rheme (Deals with emphasis)

I teach composition for academic English as a graduate student in a University, though I make plenty of mistakes, regardless. It is a general principle of academic English to be as concise as possible; However, the rules are constantly changing. My understanding is that the genre informs the type of usage for a sentence so that what is appropriate in one genre may not be in another.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to recommend you throw that stupid book away. The answer from fralau explains my reasons very well. I look at that sentence and see a structure of: 'I made noun-phrase-1 noun-phrase-2,' with noun-phrase-1 = 'my prime objective' and noun-phrase-2 = 'settling the matter'. The way most people speak now. the two noun phrases may be said in either order, depending on which you want to emphasise.

Comment: How does this address the question about the possibility / necessity of extraposition, which is what OP isasking about?